# Relacion tablas laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel

Buen dia

Tengo 2 tablas clients y companies ,en la segunda tabla estoy intentando crear la relación pero me sale un error con la llave foranea.

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error:
>   1005 Ca n't create table `usaly_bd`.`#sql-1d3c_2bb` (errno: 150
>   "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table
>   `companies` add constraint `companies_ client_id_foreign` foreign key
>   (`client_id`) references `clients` (`company_id`) )

Esta es mi migracion clients

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('clients', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('client_id');
            $table->integer('nuip')->nullable();
            $table->string('first_name')->nullable();
            $table->string('last_name')->nullable();
            $table->integer('phone')->nullable();
            $table->integer('cellphone')->nullable();
            $table->string('email')->nullable();
            $table->string('type_client')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();


        });
    }
```

Migracion companies

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('companies', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('company_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('name')->nullable();
            $table->string('business_name')->nullable();
            $table->string('douments')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();

            //Relacion
            $table->unsignedInteger('client_id');
            $table->foreign('client_id')->references('company_id')->on('clients');


        });
    }
```

Agradezco su ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes mal la columna a la que hace referencia tu `FOREIGN KEY`

actualmente esta así

```
$table->unsignedInteger('client_id');
$table->foreign('client_id')->references('company_id')->on('clients');
```

Pero debería ser así

```
$table->unsignedInteger('client_id');
$table->foreign('client_id')->references('client_id')->on('clients');
```

> Puesto que la llave foránea en tu tabla `companies` esta apuntando a
>   la tabla `clients` entonces ahi la relación no la tenías correcta y
>   como la tienes en tu pregunta tu llave foránea esta mal por que apunta
>   a la llave primaria pero de la misma tabla que la esta conteniendo

Referencia de la documentación [Foreign keys](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/migrations#foreign-key-constraints)

Comenta como te fue

Comment: Hola! Muchas gracias por tu ayuda :D era eso y el orden de mis migraciones no eran correctas ,me toco crear la tabla clients primero y luego companies ,el orden de las migraciones afecta las consultas tambien

Comment: de nada @DanielLopez recuerda siempre que lo ocupes te podemos ayudar saludos

Answer (score 0):

Estimado.

Para resolver este problema en laravel se puede realizar de la siguiente manera.

- Primero, se debe crear una migracion donde solo cree campos de tabla.
- Segundo, se debe crear una nueva migracion para añadir las claves foraneas a dicha tabla.

En este caso de esta forma:

La migracion Clients Mantener igual.
Crear una Migracion llamada "create_companies_table"

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('companies', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('company_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('name')->nullable();
            $table->string('business_name')->nullable();
            $table->string('douments')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();

            //campo con el index para la relacion
            $table->integer('client_id')->unsigned()-index('client_id_foreign');


        });
    }
```

Una segunda migracion llamada "add_fk_to_companies_table"

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('companies', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
       //crea la clave foranea hacia la tabla clients
        $table->foreign('client_id')->references('id')->on('clients')->onUpdate('RESTRICT')->onDelete('RESTRICT');

    });
}
```

Espero sea de utilidad!!!

Asegúrate de respetar el orden cronológico de las migraciones, primero la que crea la tabla, después la que crea la relación.

Comment: crear una migración para manejar solo las llaves foráneas es un paso innecesario desde que dichas llaves pueden ir perfectamente y es válido estén dentro de la migración principal

Comment: si es un paso adicional, pero con eso respetas el orden cronologioco de creacion, es mas ordenado. Que pasa si tienes que crear la tabla por X relaciones antes de la otra tabla que estas referenciando ? te dara error ya que la tabla no existe.

Para ello es recomendable crear las referencias en migraciones aparte. Desconozco si esto es considerado una buena practica en laravel, pero personalmente me ha generado menos conflictos en proyectos grandes. ¿Que opinas al respecto ?

Comment: que el orden se sigue manteniendo incluso con las llaves creadas en las mismas migraciones de las tablas donde estarán, que el tema no es relacionado con que si se hace de este modo funciona o no

Answer (score 0):

Bienvenido Daniel Lopez, el error esta en que estas relacionando tu clave foranea con un elemento que no existe en la tabla clients. 
otra cosa tambien es que tu clave primaria de la tabla clients tiene el mismo nombre que la clave foránea de la tabla companies, asi que la solución seria esta:

```
 $table->foreign('client_id')->references('client_id')->on('clients');
```

Comment: También es necesario aclarar algo mas que a futuro tienes que tener en cuenta, en tu tabla clients tu clave primaria es client_id. Laravel asume que la clave primaria de cada migración tiene el nombre "id". es necesario resaltar esto, ya que si cambias esos nombres tendrás que especificar el nombre de tu clave primaria en el respectivo modelo. Ejemplo:   protected $primaryKey = 'client_id';

Comment: Hola! Muchas gracias por tu ayuda :D era eso mas el orden de las migraciones